# How to prevent JQueryMobile CSS overriding styles for Symfony profiler?

Tags: css, symfony, jquery-mobile

I am using JQueryMobile for some of my pages. On those, the formatting for the Symfony profiler is pretty much messed up (bot with regard to page structure and formatting).

Can anyone recommend a good way of using both "style sets" (JQueryMobile and Symfony) for their respective related parts at the same time?

Here are the styles I am using in my page template that appear cause the conflict:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('themes/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('themes/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.3.min.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('themes/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.3.min.css') }}" />
```

Here's what the "content" area looks like:
[image: profiler main area]

Here's the related HTML code:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="header" class="clear-fix">
    <h1>
      <img src="..." />
    </h1>
    <div class="search">
      <form method="get" action="http://symfony.com/search" target="_blank">
        <div class="form-row">
        <label for="search-id">
          <img src="..." alt="Search on Symfony website" />
        </label> 
        <input name="q" id="search-id" type="search" placeholder="Search on Symfony website" /> 
        <button type="submit" class="sf-button">
          <span class="border-l">
            <span class="border-r">
              <span class="btn-bg">OK</span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="clear-fix">
      <div id="collector-wrapper">
        <div id="resume">
        <a id="resume-view-all" href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/search?limit=10">View last 10</a> 
        <strong>Profile for:</strong> GET 
        <a href="http://localhost/myapp/web/app_dev.php/m/">http://localhost/myapp/web/app_dev.php/m/</a> 
        <span class="date">
        <em>by ::1</em> at 
        <em>Thu, 14 Aug 2014 13:33:52 +0200</em></span></div>
        <div id="collector-content">
          <script>
[JavaScript code]
</script>
          <h2>Request GET Parameters</h2>
          <p>
            <em>No GET parameters</em>
          </p>
          <h2>Request POST Parameters</h2>
          <p>
            <em>No POST parameters</em>
          </p>
          <h2>Request Attributes</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Key</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 75%">Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>_controller</th>
                <td>
                  <pre>
VS\myapp\MobileBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction
</pre>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>_route</th>
                <td>
                  <pre>
vs_myapp_mobile_homepage
</pre>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th>_route_params</th>
                <td>
                  <pre>
[]
</pre>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <h2>Request Cookies</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Key</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 75%">Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>PHPSESSID</th>
                <td>
                  <pre>
se77r1p63robo3cijglnctmve7
</pre>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <h2>Request Headers</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 25%">Key</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 75%">Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>accept</th>
                <td>
                  <pre>
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
</pre>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a screenshot of the menu, which is rendered as a list at the far bottom of the page: [image: profiler menu]

The source code:

```
    <h2>Flashes</h2>
<p>
  <em>No flashes</em>
</p>
<div id="navigation">
  <ul id="menu-profiler">
    <li class="config">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=config">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Configuration" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Config</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="request selected">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=request">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Request" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Request</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="exception">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=exception">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Exception" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Exception</strong> </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="events">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=events">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Events" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Events</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logger">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=logger">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Logger" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Logs</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="time">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=time">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Timeline" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Timeline</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="router">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=router">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="Routing" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Routing</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="form">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=form">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Forms</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="security">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=security">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Security</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="swiftmailer">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=swiftmailer">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..." />
        </span> 
        <strong>E-Mails</strong> 
        <span class="count">
          <span>0</span>
        </span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="db">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=db">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Doctrine</strong> 
        <span class="count">
        <span>2</span> 
        <span>3 ms</span></span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="block">
      <a href="/myapp/web/app_dev.php/_profiler/f74116?panel=block">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img src="..."
          alt="" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Blocks</strong> 
        <span class="count">
          <span>0</span>
        </span></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="minimize">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Minimize toolbar" onclick="return toggleMenuPanels();">
        <span class="label">
        <span class="icon">
          <img id="minimizePanelIcon"
          src="..."
          alt="" />
        </span> 
        <strong>Minimize</strong></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search clearfix" id="searchBar">
    <h3>
    <img style="margin: 0 5px 0 0; vertical-align: middle;" width="16" height="16" alt="Search"
    src="..." />
    Search</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where exactly in the profile do these conflicts occur? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Please add HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use them together as jQuery Mobile tries to adapt normal html for mobile support.

But when you want to use the symfony profiler, you can easily commented out the css, that is what i would do :)